# powershell nuget push fails without error

Tags: powershell, nuget

I've started using powershell yesterday and am amazed by how easy it is compared to batch. I was able to resolve most issues with a little bit of search on google, but in this particular case i just don't get any error messages to work with.

This is the script in question:

https://github.com/taori/AjaxHub/blob/master/build/executePackaging.ps1

```
$apiKey = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("publish.apiKey.txt")

foreach ($package in $packages){
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content($package + ".nuspec")
    $version = $xml.package.metadata.version;

    "Setting up packacking for $package $version"

    $packagePath = ".\packages\$package\$version";

    If(Test-Path $packagePath){
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $packagePath
    }

    md -Force $packagePath

    $packArguments = "pack -Symbols -Version $version $package.nuspec -OutputDirectory $packagePath";
    "Packaging with Nuget.exe $packArguments"
    Start-Process -FilePath ".\Nuget.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $packArguments -ErrorAction Stop


    $pushArguments = "push $packagePath\$package.$version.symbols.nupkg $apiKey"
    "Pushing with Nuget.exe $pushArguments"

    Start-Process -FilePath ".\Nuget.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $pushArguments -ErrorAction Stop
    Start-Process -FilePath "https://www.nuget.org/packages/$package"
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Script done. Press <enter>"
```

It's only the push part which does not work (at least there's no update on nuget.org) or produces any errors. Does anyone know how to make it work or throw errors i can work with?

Comment: What is you check the value of `$?` after calling `nuget.exe`?

Comment: @briantist nothing sadly. tried to assign return value from process call and output it.

Comment: You could try running `.\Nuget.exe` as `&Nuget.exe` it may be exiting cleanly but with error text printed to the console that you are missing.  Generally I would avoid using `Start-Process` for launching command line applications.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there were multiple issues with my push attempt. I'm not sure why i didn't get any errors with an ordinary call but this helped me display them:

```
Invoke-Expression "$nugetPath $pushArguments" -ErrorVariable $pushOutput
"pushOutput: $pushOutput";
```

There are plenty of methods to try capture errors from a cli call but this one seems to be the easiest (and seems to work with asynchronous call errors). Unfortunately Mr Tree's suggestion did not work. I also tried versions with "2>&1", but that only pointed out syntax errors/returned nothing.

The issues i've had were the following:

- i did not apply -Wait on the pack command
- because i did not do that that pack process went off asynchronously
- my push attempt happened before the pack process was done -> file not found (i assume i did not get errors, because my push was async too)
- dns resolve failed occasionally

Script state without errors:

```
$packages = @("AjaxHub.Core","AjaxHub.MVC5")

$apiKey = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("publish.apiKey.txt")

$nugetPath = ".\Nuget.exe";

Resolve-DnsName "www.nuget.org" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
Resolve-DnsName "www.symbolsource.org" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null

foreach ($package in $packages){
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content($package + ".nuspec")
    $version = $xml.package.metadata.version;

    "Setting up packacking for $package $version"

    $packagePath = ".\packages\$package\$version";

    If(Test-Path $packagePath){
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $packagePath
    }

    md -Force $packagePath | Out-Null

    # todo add sources for -Symbols pack process
    #$packArguments = "pack -Symbols -Version $version $package.nuspec -OutputDirectory $packagePath";
    $packArguments = "pack -Version $version $package.nuspec -OutputDirectory $packagePath";
    "Packaging with Nuget.exe $packArguments"
    Start-Process -FilePath $nugetPath -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $packArguments -ErrorAction Stop -Wait

    $pushArguments = "push $packagePath\$package.$version.nupkg -ApiKey $apiKey -Timeout 60 -Verbosity normal"
    "Pushing with Nuget.exe $pushArguments" 
    Start-Process -FilePath $nugetPath -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $pushArguments -ErrorAction Stop -Wait

    Start-Process -FilePath "https://www.nuget.org/packages/$package"   

    "";
    "";
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Script done. Press <enter>"
```